# Force IIS not to impersonate user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, iis-10

I have an asp.net mvc5 application using Windows identity. Originally "All users" were allowed. The connection to the sql server backend is configured with "integrated security" and it was working fine as it impersonated the application pool user who has access.
Now I got the request to restrict access to an AD group. But by replacing the allow rule with the AD group restriction, suddenly the calls are impersonated, breaking the connection to the sql server. I have tried adding `<identity impersonate="false" />` but seems to make no difference.

Can I manage somehow this on IIS level, or do I need to handle this on application level?

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0 but for such issues you’d better contact Microsoft support or hire a consultant.

Comment: @LexLi thank you, but the article you have linked gave no additional intel to what I already know. This behavior is still strange, I could not find any documentation about how IIS or ASP.NET itself is deciding on its won to use impersonation or not. I know haw I can force impersonation to happen. I could probably also impersonate the app pool user directly, but then I would need to hardcode username and password in the configuration file - making the use of an MSA impossible.
I decided to add authorization to the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable ASP.NET Impersonation, you can try to use the following syntax:

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT/section:identity /impersonate:false
```

By default, IIS sets the impersonate attribute to false, which disables ASP.NET Impersonation authentication.

More information about [configure ASP.NET impersonation authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc730708(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) you can refer to this link.